# FILE pointer not updated in function

Tags: c, pointers

Probably a really simple answer, but I can't really see it right now. Two functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FILMS_FILE "qwerty.txt"


void InitReading(FILE * input, char * file_name)
{   
    input = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("blabla!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void ReadFilms(node * films)
{
    FILE *input = NULL;
    struct film *film_obj;

    node *next;
    bool stop = false;

    InitReading(input, FILMS_FILE);

    if (!input)
    {
        printf("pointer is null");
    }

    while (!stop)
    {
        // do other meaningful stuff
    }
}
```

As far as I know the pointer should always be updated and I shouldn't have to return a `FILE` pointer in `InitReading()`, but it appears that `input` remains the same after calling `InitReading()`. I already fixed it by changing `InitReading()` from `void` to `FILE *` type, but I can't work out, why on earth isn't the pointer updated.
Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Well, the pointer `input` very well **is** udpdated. Use a debugger to see it. You likely forgot that C is **strict** pass-by-value.

Comment: If you want to edit a pointer, pass a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: to change a value, pass a pointer, to change a pointer pass a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: Have the `InitReading()` function return the `FILE *`, like `fopen()` does.  Then use `input = InitReading(FILMS_FILE);`.  And then work out how to make the name of the file into a variable instead of a constant, so you change the file name at run time by passing a command line argument, or reading the file name from somewhere, or using an environment variable.

Comment: @MikeCAT: yes, I read that, eventually, but that's the best way to go anyway.  And passing pointers to pointers is fiddlier, if nothing else.

Comment: This must be a duplicate, but I didn't want to search log from my smartphone. Sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, function arguments are *passed by value* anf modification of arguments in callee will not affect caller's local variables.

You can use pointers to local variables to have callee modify them.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FILMS_FILE "qwerty.txt"


void InitReading(FILE ** input, char * file_name)
{   
    *input = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if (*input == NULL)
    {
        printf("blabla!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void ReadFilms(node * films)
{
    FILE *input = NULL;
    struct film *film_obj;

    node *next;
    bool stop = false;

    InitReading(&input, FILMS_FILE);

    if (!input)
    {
        printf("pointer is null");
    }

    while (!stop)
    {
        // do other meaningful stuff
    }
}
```